# Copy table (with no id) from password protected website

Tags: vba, excel, passwords

I would like to retrieve a table from my bank's website, and paste it in the same format in an excel sheet.
Thanks to a few posts on this very useful website, I managed to write a vba code that automatically :

- Open the Internet Explorer windows
- Fills in the Log-in and Password details
- Clicks on the submit Button, thus connecting me to my bank account
- Clicks on the "previous day transaction report" button, thus generating the report
- And finally shows this report in Internet Explorer

Now my problem is :
How can I copy this report (which is a table) and paste it in an excel sheet, with the Exact same format as it appears on the website ?
On the html code of the website page, this table has no "id". But it has a class, called "report". And it is the only one who has this class.

I suppose I have to use this :

```
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("report")(0).outerHTML
```

But I am not sure how to use it... Basically the simplest thing for me would be to write a last portion of code that copies the report to the clipboard, and paste it with the same format on the spreadsheet.

Any idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

i recorded a macro to get the code, using this should copy the table for you. I think its the best way for you. You have to change the URL and the webtable. This will copy it.

```
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://THE URL AFTER LOGIN WITH THE TABLE", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "SEQUENCE OF URL"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "11"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

Lets make this work!! :) step by step.

Answer (score -1):

You are right. Fill a form using it.

Try open the page, press F12 and use the console to make sure everything is right.

To fill
    document.getElementById("Id").value = "xxxxx"
    document.getElementById("Id2").value = "pass"

To click
    document.getElementById("name").click()

Comment: Hmmmm... Not sure I really understand the answer. I need to copy the table to the clipboard and then to paste it. I don't think your code does that...
Plus, the table has no idea, so getElementbyId("report") would not work...

Comment: Hi. Did you try iterating over each of the TRs and TDs TagNames and then just updating the values in excel?

Answer (score -1):

```
       Set objie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       objie.Visible = True
       With objie
           .AddressBar = False
           .StatusBar = False
           .MenuBar = False
           .Toolbar = 0

         .NAVIGATE "http://www.loginpage.com"

       While .BUSY
       Wend
       Do While .READYSTATE <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

       'first you login
       Set htmldoc = .document
       htmldoc.getElementById("UserId").Value = "login"
       htmldoc.getElementById("Password").Value = "pass"
       htmldoc.getElementById("submit-btn").Click

       End With
```

Try using this one, its first step... Makes sense to you? Im new here, so i will do my best

Comment: Hey Diogo ! Thanks a lot for your help :-)
Yes your code works, but i have already done that. I am really at the last step, where I need to copy to the clipboard a table that has the class name "Report", and paste it to my excel sheet in the same format as it displays on the website...